# (x,y) = (m_1,n_1) is the least positive solution of bx-ay= 1 while performing euclidean algorithm

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

I was reading number theory book by John Stillwell and I am stuck somewhere.

The symbolic Euclidean algorithm is used when solving linear Diophantine equations. Suppose that we run the ordinary Euclidean algorithm on the numbers $b$ and $-a$ until $1$ and $-1$ are produced, and suppose that the corresponding vector pair is $((m_1 , n_1 ), (m_2 ,n_2))$.

It claims that $(x,y) = (m_1,n_1)$ is the least positive solution of $bx-ay= 1$ and that $(x,y)= (m_2,n_2)$ is the least positive solution of $bx-ay=-1$.

It certainly looks like that but I got no clue to solve it. [image]
[image]

Comment: Not everyone has Stillwell's book, and not everyone uses Stillwell's notation. It will be hard to answer your question without knowing what you mean by running the algorithm until 1 and $-1$ are produced, and wothout knowing what your $m_i$ and $n_i$ are supposed to mean. Anyway, you might try searching this site for previous question about Euclid's algorithm. There have been many, and one may hold an answer to your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson now check.. I've attached two screenshots